# Foundation 6 range slider bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6 to create a website for a gaming community, and one of the features on the website is the ability to donate to the server.

The donation amount is chosen using a slider which should span from 1-10 EUR. However, you are unable to drag the slider all the way to 10, it just stops at 9.
I am able to move the slider handle to ten if I move it using the arrow keys, or by changing the value in the number input above the slider.

Here's a small gif showing the bug

### [image]

All the other foundation javascript plugins seems to work as intended, the code for the slider is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="sliderOutput2" style="margin-top: 2em;width:4em;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; font-weight: bolder;">
            <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="5" data-start="1" data-end="10" data-decimal="0">
                <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput2"></span>
                <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
            </div>
```

with the input at the top being the visual representation of the slider value.
This code is pretty much taken directly from the example on the Foundation documentation ([Foundation Range Slider Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#data-binding))

And here is all my jquery/javascript links

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/discord-widget.js"></script>
<script src="/js/forum-replyBox.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'forumEditor', {
    qtWidth: '100%'
}); 
</script>
<script src="/js/registrationFormValidation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/hSlider.js"></script>
<script src="/js/playerCount.js"></script>
<script     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js">    </script>
<script src="/js/shoutbox.js"></script>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['timezone'])) echo '<script src="/js/updateTimezone.js"></script>';?>
<script src="/js/inlineSVGimg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//removes all loading bars
$(window).on("load", function(){
    console.log($(".sk-cube-grid").remove());
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dropdownmenu').on(
'show.zf.dropdownmenu', function() {
  var dropdown = $(this).find('.is-dropdown-submenu');
  dropdown.css('display', 'none');
  dropdown.fadeIn('fast');
});
$('#dropdownmenu').on(
'hide.zf.dropdownmenu', function() {
  var dropdown = $(this).find('.is-dropdown-submenu');
  dropdown.css('display', 'inherit');
  dropdown.fadeOut('fast');
});
</script>
```

If you need more information about my implementation of the Foundation framework, please ask

Thanks in advance,
Regards
Daniel Holst

Comment: The issue seems to occur because of `data-start` being set to `1`. If you set it to `0`, you can correctly slide to `10`, but of course users will have the option of selecting `0`, which is what you want to avoid.
As a compromise you can set the `data-end` value to `11`, but that still won't let you move the slider all the way to the end.

Comment: Yeah I tried setting end to 11. But that still allows you to reach 11 using the arrow keys.

Comment: What about not setting the start value to 1 and adding some validation when a user tries to donate 0 euros?